# Uniquely identify MSConversation in iMessage

Tags: ios, imessage

What would be the best way to uniquely identify an `MSConversation` when developing an iMessages application?

In my case I want to give to a game object an ID of the conversation where it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Take the localParticipant ID, add to it the remoteParticipants ID ;)
Something like that :

```
var conversationID = yourConversation.localParticipantIdentifier

for participant in yourConversation.remoteParticipantIdentifiers {
   conversationID += participant
}
```

EDIT:
As noticed in comments, by doing so, you could end up with a very long ID. So the idea is to apply an hash to it, to have a constant size (MD5 is suffisant, we don't need something secure here). If it is still too long, you could crop that hash, but be aware that in that case there is a small probability for two conversations to have the same ID (depending on how much your crop).

Comment: why not, I was thinking something similar, even though can result long if there are a lot of participants.. maybe an hash..

Comment: Yep hash it, and if you want something shorter crop it then after ;) That's what I do in my games

Comment: Yep MD5 is suffisant for me as well. I will try it as soon as possible and come back to you :)

Comment: So I'm curious, how you finally did it? I'm doing that in my iMessage game app, but still happy to find a better way if there is...

Comment: Make sure you sore remoteParticipants before adding. Also not that if a new user is added to your group chat this conversation ID will become incorrect so this is not ideal for storing data on a per-conversation basis.

Answer (score 0):

The [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39583255/2057171) has a corruption issue in that if a new person is added to a group chat (or if someone is removed) your hashed *ID* will change.

A more elegant solution in my opinion is to just create your own serial number at the time of the first message being created and add it as meta-data to your message itself. (Using `NSURLComponents` of course). Then just grab that anytime a message is opened (thus launching your message app) and use that ID. Just keep it in the header of any message sent/received.

But, it depends on what you are trying to do really. The solution I've provided is great for turn-based multi-player games. It might not be good for other scenarios.